# VBA performance issue - Check before performing task

Tags: vba, excel

I've got some performance issues in my Excel Workbook.
I've got 2 different worksheets:

- the first sheet has got a lot of information
- the second sheet only shows what is useful (for someone who is not using it everyday).

On that second sheet I need to check if any rows are marked in the sorting function, and at the moment I do it this way in VBA:

```
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$12:$R$132").AutoFilter Field:=1
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$12:$R$132").AutoFilter Field:=2
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$12:$R$132").AutoFilter Field:=3
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$12:$R$132").AutoFilter Field:=4
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$12:$R$132").AutoFilter Field:=5
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$12:$R$132").AutoFilter Field:=6
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$12:$R$132").AutoFilter Field:=7
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$12:$R$132").AutoFilter Field:=8
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$12:$R$132").AutoFilter Field:=9
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$12:$R$132").AutoFilter Field:=10
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$12:$R$132").AutoFilter Field:=11
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$12:$R$132").AutoFilter Field:=12
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$12:$R$132").AutoFilter Field:=13
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$12:$R$132").AutoFilter Field:=14
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$12:$R$132").AutoFilter Field:=15
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$12:$R$132").AutoFilter Field:=16
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$12:$R$132").AutoFilter Field:=17
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$12:$R$132").AutoFilter Field:=18
```

That takes too much time compared to the task I'm performing. I'm very new to VBA and I want to know if there is a more efficient way to do it.

Comment: Are you trying to remove the filters before updating the second sheet and then put them back once the update is done?

Comment: Yes. I want to remove the filters, and afterwards I'm executing a function where i need to be sure there are no filters on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to remove the autofilters, you can use:

```
ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode = False
```

If you want to remove the filters and put them back on after your function has run, it is more complicated.

When interacting with the sheets from VBA, make sure to use this to make your code run faster:

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
'do your stuff, like turn autofilter off
'and when you are done:
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

Comment: Thanks. That was excatly what i needed. I wasn't sure what to search for :)
That was very less costly!

Comment: It actually was not that diffucult to put the filter back on after the fucntion. I my case i used:
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$12:$R$132").AutoFilter Field:=6, Criteria1:="BIRSA"

Comment: @Kano If you know in advance what the filter then it works fine that way indeed. If you don't then you need to read the state of all the filters, store the states and reapply them.

Comment: @assylias. Thanks that's good to know. I'm only at the beginning of my project and I will surely get more performance issues, because i only know the dirty code way. Hopefully I will get better in the terms, and find some answers :)